# How to round up Django money

Tags: python, django

how do i round up django money? I can't find it in the doc. Thanks in advance!

```
xxx = Money(amount=99.21, currency='SGD')
xxx= round(xxx)
```

error message

```
type Money doesn't define __round__ method
```

Comment: How about `round(xxx.amount)`?

Comment: i need the instance to be in money instance. :(

Answer (score 0):

**solution:**

Just need to reassign the amount. If there's a better way of doing this, please let me know. Thanks!!

```
xxx.amount = Decimal(round(xxx.amount))
```

Comment: May be remove `Decimal` cast. Use `xxx.amount = round(xxx.amount,2)` up to 2 decimal using `round` only

Comment: @Leistungsabfall comment should be good enough. I think stick to that answer.

Comment: @AnupYadav Decimal typeast is needed, otherwise, it will result to an error such as  `object has no attribute 'quantize'`